# Как реализовать функционал "Запомнить меня" с использованием JWT?

Tags: token, jwt

У меня есть Java-сервер и фронт на React. Для работы с JWT я использую библиотеку `io.jsonwebtoken`. У меня возник вопрос:

Каким образом можно реализовать функцию "Запомнить меня", какая часто встречается на сайтах? Причём, если пользователь эту функцию отключил, то при закрытии вкладок токен наоборот должен затираться с клиента. У меня такая идея: если пользователь нажал "Запомнить меня", то токен сохранять в localStorage, иначе в sessionStorage.

Какие есть варианты получше?

Comment: _Если данные совпадают, то пользователю возвращают токен, который потом может использоваться вместо логина и пароля._ и верно, и не верно. Токен это способ сказать серверу - "Привет, недавно виделись, моё время истекло?" (на самом деле там данные хранить можно, но это уже совсем другая история). Если истекло - или релогин, или пересоздание токена.

Comment: @InDevX ну я так грубыми словами описал:)

Comment: _то токен сохранять в localStorage, иначе в sessionStorage_ Если вы хотите его так сохранять, то перед отправкой на фронт его шифруйте. По сути, все эти "запомнить меня" это добавление в cookie какого-нибудь токена, который потом проверяется и по нему происходит автологин.

Comment: @InDevX да, токен разумеется шифруется. Не вполне понял про "запомнить меня". Не могли бы вы подробней объяснить, как именно реализуется такая функциональность?

Comment: [Входите! Аутентификация без логина и пароля, «запомнить меня»](https://habr.com/ru/post/109475/)

Comment: @InDevX ну статья немного о другом. Я просто remember me хочу реализовать и хочу понять, как его сделать

Comment: Статья как-раз об этом. Вся суть - есть токен, он хранится в куки - по нему происходит авторизация. Только на https можно делать, и даже так, это не особо безопасно